# How to clear the JAVA_HOME in linux

Tags: java, linux

I have previously installed java 1.8.0 and the JAVA_HOME was set to usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.
Now I uninstalled java and still the JAVA_HOME is set to the above path. I cleared it in etc/environment. But when i echo $JAVA_HOME it still shows the previous path. Even though I installed a new version of java and tried changing the JAVA_HOME it didn't work. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you checked the various files, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/bashrc` etc? Maybe just `grep "export JAVA_HOME"` until you find where it's defined...

Comment: try adding `export JAVA_HOME=` in last line `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: have you restarted the terminal?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://superuser.com. Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Thanks and Good luck.

Comment: @Mena grep shows exporting JAVA_HOME to  usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 in .bashrc. But when I open .bashrc with gedit it is an empty file.

Comment: @Ashbourne that likely means you are not opening the right file and gedit is creating a new one.

Comment: @Mena yeah. The actual file was hidden. I edited it. Now it is working. Thank you.

Comment: @Ashbourne no problems, glad to hear it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply spoken, there is a whole hierarchy of configuration files that might have been updated in the past and that contain that setup.

There could bee a local .profile, .bashrc; or system-wide pendants for you. So, depending on the shell you are using, the version of Linux, ... there are various places to look at. See [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html) for some guidance with bash.

You can start with a simple

```
grep JAVA_HOME .*
```

in your home directory. Next level of "escalation":

```
/etc/environment, /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/, /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: Check the usual suspects: /etc/environment, /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/, /etc/bashrc

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the shared guidance with bash. It will help me.

Comment: Sorry about first stab at comment, hit enter before I finished